# stroke doesn't work properly

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am trying to create an art brush. I choose 'tints and shades' while creating it but later it remains black, it doesn't pick  the color I want it to be.

why is this happening?

please help. :'(

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: For your Art Brush try setting the colorization to Tints.

Comment: Oh my god!! It works!!! Thank you.<3 <3 <3

Comment: One question, why those two options are greyed out? (last attached image)  I need to set it with one of those ..

Comment: It seems a Brush can only be center aligned to a path. To move the brush stroke you have to manipulate the path itself- white arrow ?

Comment: no no, its not that. I can set stroke either in middle , or inside or outside. In this case it dsnt work like that. what you told me is manipulating the stoke I am not talking about that.

Comment: A "Basic" path must be closed to be able to set stroke to anything other than center aligned. Otherwise Illustrator does not know which is the inside or the outside. Any Brush applied to a path can only be center aligned- even if the path is closed. Perhaps ask another question for further explanation on this- it is really a separate question.

Comment: what that question should be? how to set stroke properly? am serious? i will ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tints and Shades in your Brush Colorization settings will change all the colors  ***except black and white*** to the stroke color you choose.

This is why your stroke setting did not change the brush color- your brush was only black.

Setting the colorization to Tints will change the entire Art Brush color to your chosen stroke color.

Answer (score 1):

Illustrator itself says:

> The colors your brush paints with depend on three things:
>
> 1. The colorization method you choose.
> 2. The current stroke color, found in the Color panel.
> 3. For the Hue Shift colorization method, the "key color" you select from the artwork with the Key Color Eyedropper.

In short, before you create an art brush select the art itself, give it an another color located in the Color panel and start creating the art work.

[image]

Comment: I know these. still it didn't work.